# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - opencv-python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

when i try to conda install opencv-python

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> `- opencv-python`

Comment: `conda install opencv` should do the trick.